# I need JAX-WS runtime on Tomcat. Is it ok to put "jax-ws/lib/*" to "tomcat/lib"?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws, apache-axis

I need JAX-WS runtime on Tomcat.

Is it OK to put "jax-ws/lib/*" to "tomcat/lib" ?

Does one need any Axis, Axis2 libs in Tomcat if he puts jax-ws/lib into tomcat/lib?

At least, any of axis*.jar are needed for Tomcat to function properly?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you should avoid putting jar files in the tomcat/lib folder. Tomcat doesn't need jar files other than those originally to be found in its lib directory.

If you need a jar file you should put it in WEB-INF/lib folder of your application. This will save you a lot of headaches with jars versioning.